# Найдите лексические ошибки, объясните их. Предложения исправьте

Tags: лексика

1. Первая трудность произошла со стройматериалами.
2. Резю-мируя, можно кратко обобщить: предпринята очередная попытка дис-кредитировать нашу фирму.
3. Командировочный уже выполнил зада-ние полностью.
4. Кафе, бистро, как и ателье разного профиля, должны функционировать по субботам.
5. Он не откладывал дела в длинный ящик.

Comment: Опять домашние задания?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы упростить вам выполнение домашнего задания, можно лишь предложить наводящие вопросы.

1. Бывает ли трудность разновидностью происшествия?
2. Можно ли резюмировать не кратко?
3. Применимо ли прилагательное "командировочный" (командировочное удостоверение, командировочные расходы) к людям?
4. А есть ли здесь ошибки, подобные ходячей "в том числе ателье разного профиля"?
5. Как на самом деле звучит поговорка о "ящике"?